# Как правильно произвести нормализацию?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, scikit-learn

Изучаю [пример TimeseriesGenerator](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-use-keras-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-data/). Для нормализации в нем используется [минимаксное масштабирование](https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html). К примеру, при обучении, я заполняю `MinMaxScaler` некими данными с помощью метода `fit`. В примере используются одни и те же данные для обучения и проверки.

Как правильно заполнять `MinMaxScaler` при оценке и прогнозе если на вход подаются другие данные? Нужно перезаполнить `MinMaxScaler` новыми данными или оставить тот вариант на котором происходило обучение?

Условный пример:

```
#Обучение
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train_data)
train_data = scaler.transform(train_data)
...
#Выход
```

Другая сессия

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
#Какой из вариантов правильный?
scaler.fit(train_data) #Этот?
scaler.fit(test_data) #Или этот?
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [MinMaxScaler.fit_transform()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.fit_transform) для обучающей выборки и [MinMaxScaler.transform()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.transorm):

```
train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data)
```

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Comment: Все таки я не понял смысла повторного заполнения данными. То, что числа будут приведены к диапазону - это хорошо, Но не будет ли он давать ошибки при прогнозе? Ведь одни и те же числа, масштабированные с разными диапазонами минимума и максимума, будут уже различаться. Как в вашем примере, где в учебных данных число 9 в колонке "c" после нормализации станет 1, а в тестовых то же число будет 0.

Comment: @ВладимирПетров, да, пожалуй не стоит переобучать `scaler` на новых данных... Сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: Получается, что если тестовые данные имеют другой диапазон значений, то нужно заново переобучать сеть на новых данных?

Comment: @ВладимирПетров, если есть такая возможность то лучше обучать на всех доступных данных.

Comment: Понятно, какой-то неудачный пример просто попался. Автор, видимо, привел его для демонстрации возможностей, но реально кто может сказать насколько изменятся биржевые индексы в будущем.